# create dependent radio buttons in different rows

Tags: flutter, select, radio-button

Currently, I can only use independent radio buttons to realize my desired layout.

[image: see this current layout]

But, I need to have the shown radio buttons with different options (option 1 - 6) and only allow single select across the page and have this selection accessible when clicking the button.
How can I realize this in flutter(flow)? Do I need a custom function?
Thanks!

I also tried check boxes but there I have basically the same problem to realize single select.

Answer (score 0):

You can enforce a single selection mode on your radio buttons by setting the `groupValue` property. This here gives you an example for two radio buttons provided you store the currently selected value in some property `int? _selectedValue`.

You can change the type of course, I used an integer for this example. More info can be found in the [documentation of the Radio class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Radio-class.html).

```dart
return Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    ListTile(
      title: const Text('Value 1'),
      leading: Radio<int>(
        value: 1,
        groupValue: _selectedValue,
        onChanged: (int? value) {
          setState(() {
            _selectedValue = value;
          });
        },
      ),
    ),
    ListTile(
      title: const Text('Value 2'),
      leading: Radio<int>(
        value: 2,
        groupValue: _selectedValue,
        onChanged: (int? value) {
          setState(() {
            _selectedValue = value;
          });
        },
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```